# Subscript Dimension Error When Dynamically Creating Buttons in AutoIt

Tags: button, autoit

I'm writing an AutoIt script to make GUI buttons by looping through an array of button definitions.

It's a script that I'll be adding/removing buttons to/from quite often, so I thought a loop makes sense.  I add the button handle, button text, and function name to bind the button to an array called `$buttons`.  The button parameters are saved to a row of the `$buttons` array as a pipe delimited string.

```
Func make_buttons()

    local $i = 1
    Local $bHandles[Ubound($buttons)]
    _arraydisplay($bHandles)
    For $button In $buttons
        local $params= StringSplit($button,"|")
        local $top = $i*40
        local $left = 10
        local $width = 100
        Global $bHandles[$i] = GUICtrlCreateButton($params[1],$left,$top,$width)
        GUICtrlSetOnEvent($bHandles[$i],$params[2])

        $i = $i+1
    Next
EndFunc
```

I'm getting this error on execution:

> Global $params[1] = ^ERROR
>   Error: Missing subscript dimensions in "Dim" statement

Any help clarifying what the error means is appreciated.

**Update**

@Sachadee's answer below clued me along to the fact athat I had been using the `Global` keyword to declare the handle variable to `GuiCtrlCreateButton()` while trying to use a variable as the name.  Leaving off the Global keyword helped me eliminate the error I was receiving.  My final button creation lines of code worked as this:

```
Func make_buttons()

    local $i = 1
    For $button In $buttons
        local $params= StringSplit($button,"|")
        local $top = $i*40
        local $left = 10
        local $width = 100
        Global $handle = $params[2] & "_handle"
        $handle = GUICtrlCreateButton($params[1],$left,$top,$width)
        GUICtrlSetOnEvent($handle,$params[2])
        $i = $i+1
    Next
EndFunc
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit :

You're defining an array structure `Local $bHandles[Ubound($buttons)]` with the place for [N] elements. But you're not defining the content of this array. And then  you're trying to redefine it with another value with the `Global`: 
`Global $bHandles[$i] = GUICtrlCreateButton($params[1],$left,$top,$width)`.

Here's a better way to do it :

```
#include <GUIConstants.au3>
#include <ButtonConstants.au3>

Global $AllButtons[4] = ["3","Button1","Button2","Bouton3"]

GuiCreate ("Title", 120, 200)
$Btn_Start = GUICtrlCreateDummy()
For $i = 1 To $AllButtons[0]
    local $top = $i*40
    local $left = 10
    local $width = 100
    GUICtrlCreateButton($AllButtons[$i],$left,$top,$width)
Next
$Btn_End = GUICtrlCreateDummy()
GUISetState ()

While 1
    $Msg = GUIGetMsg()
    Switch $msg
        Case $GUI_EVENT_CLOSE
            Exit
        Case $Btn_Start To $Btn_End
            MsgBox(0, "Test", GUICtrlRead($Msg))
    EndSwitch
 Wend
```

Comment: Why is this the better way?  Can you clarify the error message I posted?  Your suggestion ignores the array of button information being parsed in my OP.

Comment: The array of button is here simulated with the array `$allButtons`. You can replace it with your array and it will work.